# dos o más filas a columnas

Tags: excel

tengo un documento  con  60k de registros,  pero las columnas estan  de la siguiente manera[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y yo quisiera  tenerlo de esta forma  para que solo me quede una vez el nombre de la persona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: vuelve a mirar por favor [ask]. no se entiende nada de tu pregunta.. que es un documento? como es que lo generaste? como lo queres transformar?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que crearte una tabla dinámica.

Yo he emulado tus datos tal cual los has puesto.

> [Crear una tabla dinámica para analizar datos de una hoja de
>   cálculo](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/crear-una-tabla-din%C3%A1mica-para-analizar-datos-de-una-hoja-de-c%C3%A1lculo-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Para configurarla:

1. El campo NOMBRE al área de filas
2. El campo AÑO al área de columnas
3. Los campos PAGO1 y PAGO2 al área de valores.
4. Desactiva totales generales
5. Pone formato tabular desde Diseño de Informe

Te quedará una tabla dinámica así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es justo lo que quieres.